# Move to application in sd card in htc desire 620

Tags: applications, external-sd, app2sd

I have android phone htc desire 620 I want to move my all apps in sd card. I have tried but not able to do it. generally in another phone options is available in setting->apps->move to sd card
but in my phone it's not available so please suggest me how can I transfer my app to sd card

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: Our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) would be a good start for your research on this, as are the [most frequented questions using that tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app2sd?sort=frequent).

Comment: @rjt.rockx  I don't know how can I do that